How to merge json object with same keys?
Here are the 2 items in one array:
{
  "SysID": "12345",
  "Name": "abc"
}
{
  "SysID": "12345",
  "Name": "def"
}
{
  "SysID": "23456",
  "Name": "hij"
}
{
  "SysID": "23456",
  "Name": "klm"
}
{
  "SysID": "23456",
  "Name": "nop"
}

I would like to transform "SysID" into key and "Name" as the value of it in array:
{
  "12345": [
    "abc",
    "def",
  ],
  "23456": [
    "hij",
    "klm",
    "nop",
  ],
}

May I know how could I do that in jq?

There is no array in your source data, is that intended?

Using reduce():
reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.SysID] += [$i.Name])

Will give
{
  "12345": [
    "abc",
    "def"
  ],
  "23456": [
    "hij",
    "klm",
    "nop"
  ]
}

When called with --slurp to wrap those object into an array.

JqPlay Demo

Thanks @0stone0, you just saved my life

Is there a generic way to merge these? I have had this issue in the past for whole objects.

Not sure what you're trying to ask @ChristianBongiorno, you might just want to ask a new question. See [ask].

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79156798/in-jq-how-to-merge-an-array-of-object-into-1-object-with-an-array-of-values

You can also use group_by to merge
jq 'group_by(.SysID)|map({(.[0].SysID): map(.Name)})|add'

$ jq 'group_by(.SysID)'    
[
  [{"SysID":"12345","Name":"abc"},{"SysID":"12345","Name":"def"}],
  [{"SysID":"23456","Name":"hij"},{"SysID":"23456","Name":"klm"},{"SysID":"23456","Name":"nop"}]
]

$ jq 'group_by(.SysID)|map({(.[0].SysID): map(.Name)})'
[
  {"12345":["abc","def"]},
  {"23456":["hij","klm","nop"]}
]

$ jq 'group_by(.SysID)|map({(.[0].SysID): map(.Name)})|add'
{
  "12345": [
    "abc",
    "def"
  ],
  "23456": [
    "hij",
    "klm",
    "nop"
  ]
}

