in jq, how to merge an array of object into 1 object with an array of values
Let's say I have this json:
[
  {
    "first": 12355,
    "second": "abc"
  },
  {
    "first": 89010,
    "second": "def"
  },
  {
    "first": 23423,
    "second": "hij"
  },
  {
    "first": 23456,
    "second": "klm"
  },
  {
    "first": 11111,
    "second": "nop"
  }
]

And I would like (a generic form) that merges them into 1 object where the value of each key is merged into an array of the corresponding values:
{
    "first" : [12355,89010,23423,23456,11111],
    "second" : ["abc","def","hij","klm","nop"]
}

I was trying this, but it produces no output at all.
reduce .[] as $final (
    {};
    ((. | keys) as $k |
        map(
            ( (.[$k] // []) += ($final[$k] // []))
        )
    )
)


I'd use to_entries (to access keys and values) as part of the iteration:
reduce (.[] | to_entries[]) as $e ({}; .[$e.key] += [$e.value])

Demo
Here's another way using group_by to bring the matching items together:
map(to_entries[]) | group_by(.key) | map({(first.key): map(.value)}) | add

Demo
Output:
{
  "first": [
    12355,
    89010,
    23423,
    23456,
    11111
  ],
  "second": [
    "abc",
    "def",
    "hij",
    "klm",
    "nop"
  ]
}


Note: These solutions expect all input objects to have the same set of keys. Missing keys in single objects will lead to shortened, thus potentially misaligned output arrays. To readjust the arrays by pitching in null values, normalize the objects before destructuring them into entries by reconstructing them using a pre-defined set of keys, e.g. {first, second}:
reduce (.[] | {first, second} | to_entries[]) as $e …
# or
map({first, second} | to_entries[]) | group_by(.key) …

If, however, the actual set of keys is dynamic or unknown, screen and collect them first, e.g. using (map(keys[]) | unique) as $keys, then normalize based on that set using pick(.[$keys[]]) (pick was introduced with jq 1.7; older versions could use .[$keys[]] //= null instead):
(map(keys[]) | unique) as $keys
| reduce (.[] | pick(.[$keys[]]) | to_entries[]) as $e …
# or
(map(keys[]) | unique) as $keys
| map(pick(.[$keys[]]) | to_entries[]) | group_by(.key) …


This is exactly what I was looking for so I could compact JSON. Example:
du -sh results_normalized.json
30M    results_normalized.json
jq merge results_normalized.json > merged.json
du -sh merged.json
19M     merged.json


Is it too late to add 1 request? If the object being merged in doesn't have the key, then it yields null instead of 2 arrays of different size? I want to be able to reverse this process

@ChristianBongiorno To compensate for missing items, you need to define what can be considered "complete" object with no missing items (against which "incomplete" ones can determine their defects). Given the two approaches from my post, just change to_entries[] to {first, second} | to_entries[], i.e. prefilter with {first, second} which normalizes the inputs (Demo1, Demo2).

Right, so I would need to do something like get all keys from all object, as a set, then during the reduction process, use those uses for the lookup. If a key isn't in the lookup, it should still produce a value of null

@ChristianBongiorno If you don't know the keys in advance, you could first check the input array and collect an array of unique keys into a variable, say $keys, then use pick(.[$keys[]]) instead of {first, second} (Demo1, Demo2).

I thought I was pretty good with jq, but you take it for sure. That works very well. Perhaps update the answer with that as an alternative?

Or for simplicity, consider using transpose, e.g.
map([.[]]) | transpose | {first: first, second: .[1]}


While I like transpose for that usecase (which works also for the reverse), THIS solution does not work if the order of "first" and "second" is changed in some entries.
A first step like map([.first, .second]) fixes that.

@A.H. Yes, the emphasis was on transpose and "e.g.".

This assumes you know the keys in advance. The reduce method succeeds without such assumptions. Although, I ran a bench test and it took 81.99s user 1.71s system 99% cpu 1:24.18 total on my mac m2 to run on a 30mb json file. A faster solution would be handy
